# How to add every nth cell in a column in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have 2 spreadsheets.

Spreadsheet 1: has a number in every  6th row in the A column
Spreadsheet 2: I want to add every number in every 6th cell in the A column into a cell on this spreadsheet

Comment: when you say add, do you mean arithmetic add where you are summing the numbers, or do you mean add as in adding to the sheet so you have 1 continuous list on spreadsheet 2 which is every 6th cell?  Another very good question is what is the first cell in column A on spreadsheet 1 that you want to pull.  The address of this cell sets your pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the following formula in any cell of `Sheet2`:

```
=SUM(Sheet1!A1:A60*(MOD(ROW(Sheet1!A1:A60),6)=0))
```

This is an array formula so commit by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Change range `A1:A60` as required.

Comment: Wow fantastic. Is there anyway to make it so it can start at A0? So it will add for example number 6, 12, 18 because atm it does 1,7,13 etc?

Comment: @EdBriscoe A0 would be a tough one as that cell address does not exist!

Comment: @EdBriscoe if you look at my answer, you can modify the code to select the first time you want to start adding.

Answer (score 1):

In case You would like to go for Non Array Formula and as I understand you want to add every 6 th value. You can use the following formula on sheet2 column `B1` as a helper column and fill down by simple enter only. I am assuming your data in column `A` of both the sheets.

```
 =IF(MOD(ROW($A1),6)+MOD(ROW(Sheet1!$A1),6)=0,A1+Sheet1!$A1," ")
```

Snapshot shows the results obtained.

[image: Snapshot showing results]

In case you want total sum other answers have covered that.

Answer (score 1):

I think sumproduct is a nifty solution for this. We multiply the values we want to ignore by 0 and the ones we want to keep by one.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(ROW(A1:A16), 6)=0), A1:A16)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a VBA macro to accomplish this.

```
Sub everySixth()
 Dim f As String
 f = "=Sheet1!A6"
 Dim i As Long

 For i = 1 To 5
  f = f & "+Sheet1!A" & (i * 6)
 Next

 ActiveCell.formula = f
End Sub
```