# How to skip every nth row in Excel column Sum

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table which I have copied from the internet and pasted in Excel. The data pasted is however not clean. I want to add the 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th... row from the column, while skipping 2,3,5,6,8,9...th row. And I'd like that solution to be in one cell, that is without adding a helper column.

Here is a snapshot of my [demo table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuHwW.png). Hope this gives you an idea of what I am trying achieve.

I've searched the internet found this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37439655/how-to-add-every-nth-cell-in-a-column-in-excel). But I just can't modify the formula to get around my solution. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing you have a header in your column.
Enter the following formula in your desired cell where you want the sum value

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A13),(--(MOD(ROW(A2:A13),3)=2)))
```

Explanation:

1. `MOD(ROW(A2:A13),3)=2` Checks for rows where row_number %% 3 = 2 and returns an array of boolean(TRUE or FALSE for each match)

Output : `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A13),(--({TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;FALSE})))`

2. The double negative converts the boolean values to numeric 1(TRUE) or 0(FALSE).

Output: `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A13),({1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0}))`

3. `SUMPRODUCT` multiplies the above array with the data array of `A2:A16` and adds the product result.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about using sumproduct? This function is greatly versatile and should do the trick. The idea is that the double negative sign casts the boolean to a one or zero so your false elements (aka any n where n%3 <> 1) get multiplied by zero so they are, in effect, excluded from your sum.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(ROW(A1:A16), 3)=1), A1:A16)
```